# zip the Azure Storage files and share Readonly Download Link C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Does Azure Storage provide out of box feature to zip selected files and share download link from C# Dotnet core code?
If not the approach i forsee is download files create a zip in my C# code.

Comment: why do not you write such code in c#

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage itself does not provide an out-of-the-box feature to zip selected files and share a download link directly.

you could try following below steps to achieve your requirement:

1)Use Azure Blob Storage client libraries to download the files from Azure Storage to your application's local storage or memory.

2)Once the files are downloaded, use .NET's `System.IO.Compression` namespace to create a zip file. You can either store this zip file temporarily on the server's local disk or keep it in memory, depending on your application's needs and the size of the files.

3)After creating the zip file, upload it back to Azure Blob Storage.

4)Create a SAS URL for the uploaded zip file. This URL will provide access to the file with specific permissions and for a defined time period. Share this SAS URL with the users who need to download the zip file. This URL will allow them to download the file directly from Azure Storage.

Here is the sample code:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.SAS;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public async Task<string> CreateAndShareZipAsync(string containerName, List<string> fileNames)
{
    BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient("your_connection_string");
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

    using MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            var blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

            ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = zip.CreateEntry(fileName);

            using Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open();
            await blobDownloadInfo.Value.Content.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
        }
    }

    string zipFileName = "your_zip_file_name.zip";
    BlobClient zipBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(zipFileName);
    zipStream.Position = 0; 
    await zipBlobClient.UploadAsync(zipStream);

    BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder
    {
        BlobContainerName = containerName,
        BlobName = zipFileName,
        Resource = "b", // b for blob
        StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24) // link validity
    };
    sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

    string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential("your_account_name", "your_account_key")).ToString();
    string sasUrl = zipBlobClient.Uri + "?" + sasToken;

    return sasUrl;
}
```